# Pagination on static page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have this code on static page

```
$novo = new WP_Query('cat=3');
while ($novo->have_posts()) : $novo->the_post(); ?>
    <div id="entry">
    <!-- POST FORMAT HERE -->
    </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>


    <div class="navigation">
    <span class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></span>
    <span class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;') ?></span>
    </div>
```

This kind of navigation doesn't work here. Please who can help me with this, 
I will be very very grateful

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
    if(!$paged)
    {
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    }
    if(!$paged)
    {
        $paged = 1;
    }
$novo = new WP_Query('cat=3&paged=' . $paged);
```